# Create associative array with a static string for values and keys from an array column

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array object like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => sam
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => tim
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => nic
        )

)
```

And I want to have this:

```
Array
(
    [sam] => sample text
    [tim] => sample text
    [nic] => sample text
)
```

My current approach:

```
$arr = array();

foreach($multi_arr as $single_arr) {
    $arr[$single_arr->name] = "sample text";
}
```

Is there a cleaner/better approach than this? Thanks

Comment: Is the array produced by `json_decode()`?

Comment: @axiac no, this data structure is from db.

Comment: If this data is coming from a database, then what is stopping you from adding  a static string as a column in your SELECT clause (aliased as `static_text` then merely calling `array_column($resultSet, 'static_text', 'name')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map` to get all the keys, then use `array_fill_keys` to populate the final array.

```
$arr = array_fill_keys(array_map(function($e) {
    return $e->name;
}, $multi_arr), "sample text");
```

If `sample text` is part of the stdClass object:

```
$arr = array_merge(...array_map(function($e) {
    return [$e->name => $e->description];
}, $multi_arr));
```

Comment: What if "sample text" is dynamic?

Comment: is "sample text" the same for all? put it in a variable, and use that

Comment: $multi_arr has 'description' which i can call $single_arr->description to populate "sample text". Sorry about this, should have include this in my question